# Android layout margins making width be 0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

When I'm trying to change the left or right margins of something in Java it doesn't work. Instead, it shrinks the button to where the width is 0dp. 
Here is my code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams TwoPos = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ezONEaONE.getLayoutParams();
TwoPos.bottomMargin = 515;
TwoPos.leftMargin = 50;
ezONEaONE.setLayoutParams(TwoPos);
```

My button in the layout:

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/ez1a1"
    android:id="@+id/ez1a1"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:ignore="Deprecated,NewApi,RtlHardcoded,TextViewEdits"
    android:onClick="Ez1A1"
    android:minWidth="88dp"
    android:minHeight="46dp"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ez1N1" />
```

Comment: Can you share your layout file?

Comment: I added the layout file for the button

Answer (score 0):

```
Button ezOneaOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ezOneaOneIDName);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams TwoPos = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ezONEaOne.getLayoutParams();
TwoPos.setMargins(50, 0, 0, 515); //left, top, right, bottom
ezOneaOne.setLayoutParams(TwoPos);
```

---

You might have to put `dp` at the end. Sorry if it doesn't work.

Comment: I already had dp at the end of it and even if I didn't it automatically adds dp tp it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ez1N1"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/ez1N1"
```

Comment: For your question, friend.